# Order for tevilah and kashering

Tags: halacha, priorities, kashering-kosherization, tevilas-keilim-dipping

This is an extension of [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83618/kashrut-of-second-hand-silverware?noredirect=1#comment260097_83618).

If one purchases used keilim from a non-Jew which would require both tevilah and kashering, which order is prescribed: tevilah then kashering or kashering then tevilah?

Answer (score 6):

First Kasher them and then dunk them in the Mikva. ([ShA YD 121:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%90_%D7%91))

If you did it the wrong way some say you have to dunk them again.

Answer (score 3):

Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 121:2 - Kashering then Tevila

> לקח מהן כלים שנשתמש בהם בחמין, בין שהם  של מתכת או של עץ או אבן,  מגעילן  ואחר כך מטבילן, אם הם של מתכת, והם מותרים. ואם הטבילן ואחר כך הגעילן, מותרים. ויש אומרים שצריך ה לחזור  ולהטבילן.

Comment: http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De'ah.121.2?lang=bi (Double AA was first)

Comment: "hazoriz niskar" beat me to it!

Comment: Consider adding the translation into your answer.